# Как работает система голосования как на stackoverflow?

Tags: jquery, frontend

Как реализовать такую же на jquery? Когда пользователь кликает по стрелочке, jquery добавляет к ней класс и отправляет ajax-запрос на сервер - стрелочка загорается, в БД записывается - с этим понятно. А как быть после обновления страницы? При выводе новостей делать запрос в БД и добавлять "класс подсветки" к соответствующей стрелочке или при голосовании в куки записывать id стрелочки и потом их подсвечивать javascript'ом, и как тогда при авторизации массив этот в куки помещать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше всё, что можно сделать на сервере, — делать на сервере и не нагружать железо пользователя.

Посмотри, как ВКонтакте работает. Он присылает новости в ленту кусками сформированного HTML кода и не навязывает кучу обработчиков на лайки и репосты при каждом изменении DOM дерева; просто везде есть вызов функций `onclick`, `onmouseenter` и т. д., прямо inline. Это и позволяет так быстро работать.